# Generics как создавать списки с разными типами

Tags: java

Когда читал про Generics, все казалось просто и понятно, пока не дошло до реализации
У меня есть несколько классов

```
public class ItemUser implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
public class ItemCity implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

и т.д.
в этом классе мне надо создать список с одним из этих типов

```
public class Data {
  private List<?> list;

  public List<?> getList(...) {
     return list = 
  }
  public void init() {
     list = getList(...);
  }
}
```

Как это сделать?

Вот так будет правильно?:

```
public class Data<T> {
  private List<T> list;
  public Data(T myType){
     list = new ArrayList<T>();
  }
}
public class ItemData {
  private Data<T> data;
  public void init() {
     data = new Data<ItemUser>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю можно так Generic

```
public class Data<T> {
  private List<T> list;

  public List<T> getList(...) {
     return list = 
  }
  public void init() {
     list = getList(...);
  }
}
```

либо конкретный класс

```
public class ItemUserData {
  private List<ItemUser> list;

  public List<ItemUser> getList(...) {
     return list = 
  }
  public void init() {
     list = getList(...);
  }
}
```

Можно обобщить тогда проводить типы будите в ручную

```
public class Data {
  private List<Object> list;

  public List<Object> getList(...) {
     return list = 
  }
  public void init() {
     list = getList(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Если взять ваш первый вариант, то так будет правильно. Я добавил код в вопрос.